# deleting all private IP addresses

Tags: sed

Currently I am working on a project where I have a file full of IP addresses I want to delete the IP adddresses that are private (whole range) and using bash to accomplish it. I do make a match of private addresses but unable to delete it.

I have tried:

```
sed -i '/(192)\.(168)(\.([2][0-5][0-5]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){2}/d' validIPOnly
```

same for

```
127.x.x.x,172.16.x.X,10.x.x.x
```

Comment: 1. `{2}` notation will not work on sed. use `-E`. 2. `d` will delete the entire line, not the match

Comment: 172.16.0.0/12 -> [range from 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces)

Comment: thanks for helping, i will test it in a moment

Comment: thank you nu11p01n73R and Cyrus

Comment: thanks for pointing out Cyrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using capture groups with `sed` you either need to escape the `(` `)` or specify option `-E`:

```
$ sed -E -i '/(...)...'
```

or

```
$ sed -i '/\(...\)...`
```

*For GNU sed only* use the `-r` option instead of `-E`.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Thanks for the edit; in the Mac version of Bash (GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
 there is no `-r` option, so `-E` would be the equivalent I believe.

Comment: Side note: I would omit the `-i` switch in an answer. Either you explain that it requires an argument on non-GNU sed's or simply leave it up to the OP to change his files *in place*. I recommend the latter, especially since that prevents from data loss as well.

Comment: Oh, I thought both `-r` and `-E` work on Mac both but `-r` is portable. Sorry for the edit then

Comment: @hek2mgl: No worries, you meant well by the edit :) OS X `sed` is (unfortunately) very limited in comparison to what is standard on Linux.

Comment: thanks l'L'l and hek2mgl my problem is solved as it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @hek2mgl `-E` works on both mac and newer GNU seds. `-r` is GNU sed only.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh, I mixed that. Thanks for that information!